# "Magic Mouse" is Fidgety

Tags: mouse

Recently purchased a MacStudio and a "Magic Mouse."

The Magic Mouse is fidgety.  I'll click 7 for top view and it will "move?"

Has anyone had similar experience and able to correct it?

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: Can you post a screen recording of what's going on? This kind of thing is easier to debug by seeing it.

Comment: Hi, I've never recorded my screen before -- learning how to do it and then will post.  Also, Apple exchanged the mouse and hopefully the new one will be "ok?"

Comment: That might be it.